# Get SchemaType by ObejctId in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

From the front end i am getting an obejectId of an element.
The object element can belong to one of 2 models. 
It can be an object Id of either Containers Schema or Folders schema.
Is there a way to get schema type from objectId in mongoosejs

Comment: No, you should either use the same schema for both types of objects, of use additional dictionary (e.g. additional collection) to resolve `ObjectID`'s into schema types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

Here the document http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 3-byte machine identifier,
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

---

You can get Schema from a document like this:

```
doc.schema
```

example:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({name: String, pass: String});
var User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

User.findOne( {_id: your_id}, function (err, doc) {
    console.log(doc.schema)
})
```